# Find the most occuring column in data frame

Tags: r, count

I want to find the column of a data frame that occurres the most in a certain data frame. For example, the following data frame:

`as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,4,6,9,20),c(2,4,7,7,3),c(4,7,6,4,2),c(1,4,6,9,20),c(4,7,6,4,2),c(7,4,6,4,2)))`

My first idea is to order the columns in the data frame so I get:
`as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,4,6,9,20),c(2,3,4,7,7),c(2,4,4,6,7),c(1,4,6,9,20),c(2,4,4,6,7),c(2,4,4,6,7)))` 
and then finding the most occurring column in this data frame. It then should return `c(2,4,4,6,7)`. How can this by done in R?

Comment: What shall happen if there are many 1st places in the ranking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically same solution as of @jay.sf, but using tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dataset <- as.data.frame(x = cbind(c(1, 4, 6, 9, 20),
                                   c(2, 4, 7, 7, 3),
                                   c(4, 7, 6, 4, 2),
                                   c(1, 4, 6, 9, 20),
                                   c(4, 7, 6, 4, 2),
                                   c(7, 4, 6, 4, 2)))

dataset %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = ~ paste0(sort(.), collapse = "")) %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  table() %>%
  which.max() %>%
  `[`(dataset, .)
#>   V2
#> 1  2
#> 2  4
#> 3  7
#> 4  7
#> 5  3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works! By this command, you can count the number of occurrences of ```c(2,4,7,7,3)``` and all of its variations: ```target <- c(2,4,7,7,3)
sum(sapply(dataset, function(x) setequal(target, na.omit(x))))```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could `paste` the numbers and count them in a `table`, then choose `which.max`.

```
d1[, which.max(table(sapply(d1, paste, collapse="")))]
# [1] 2 4 4 6 7
```

***Data***

```
d1 <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 4, 6, 9, 20), X2 = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 7), 
X3 = c(2, 4, 4, 6, 7), X4 = c(1, 4, 6, 9, 20), X5 = c(2, 
4, 4, 6, 7), X6 = c(2, 4, 4, 6, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to match multiple columns:

```
# Creating a table of pasted & sorted column values
counts_df1 <- table(do.call(paste, data.frame(t(sapply(df1, sort)))))

# If you want the sorted order returned as a single element vector:
names(counts_df1[counts_df1 == max(counts_df1)])
[1] "2 4 4 6 7"
```

Or, you could do this to index the column in your dataframe:

```
# Creating collapsed strings from columns
df1_vec <- sapply(df1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))

# Counting the frequency of each collapsed strings
df1_colsum <- colSums(outer(df1_vec, df1_vec, `==`))

# Subsetting the dataframe based on the most frequent columns that are not duplicates
df1[, df1_colsum == max(df1_colsum) & !duplicated(df1_vec)]
[1] 4 7 6 4 2
```

Comment: But this code does not take ```c(7,4,6,4,2)``` into account in the counting

Comment: @LuukvanGasteren, I was thinking about this and I believe the table method (that does not use `names` is stumbling into the correct answer for the sample data. It is subsetting the first max value (`which.max` selects the first in the case of multiple maxes) of the `table` that does not include the same number of columns as the df. It just so happens they are both in the second position (of the table and the df). Anyway, I corrected the code in my answer. Double check what I am saying about the other code as well! Good luck!